# How to add values to Supplier<List>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I feel I have some wrong interpretation of Supplier use-case.
Here is an example where I want to add value to a List. But when I try to fetch the list from supplier, it shows as empty.

```
Supplier<List<String>> str = ArrayList::new;
        
str.get().add("Hi");
System.out.println(str.get().size());
```

Returns: 0

Comment: You are missing the big picture. This is not what `Supplier` is used for. Check [When we should use Supplier in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40244571/10819573)

Answer (score 4):

`Supplier<List<String>>` is a function that gets invoked whenever the `get` method is run.

In your case, `str` is similar to the following lambda expression:

```
Supplier<List<String>> str = () -> new ArrayList<>();
```

Which means that every time `str.get()` is called, the *function* gets called, and the body `new ArrayList<>()` is executed, thus resulting in a new list every time.

If you want the `Supplier` to always return the same list, then you need to capture it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Supplier<List<String>> str = () -> list;
```

This way, every time `str.get()` runs, it will just return the same list it captured. But, IMO, this doesn't seem like good practice, it would seem rather correct to just keep a reference to the variable instead of keeping it behind a Supplier (which implies a function producing a value).

Comment: There’s also the option to create a new, decorating supplier that will always perform the add operation on the created list `{ Supplier<List<String>> tmp = str; str = () -> { List<String> list = tmp.get(); list.add("Hi"); return list; }; }`

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `str.get()` will instantiate a new `List`, which will be empty.

Your two calls to `str.get()` return two different instances. You added an element to the first `List`, but the second `List` is empty.

You have to store a reference to the created `List` if you want to have access to it:

```
List<String> list = str.get();
list.add("Hi");
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: Eran, thank you for the explanation. My use case is this. I have to declare several type  of Lists in a method. Now I want to make them lazy so have wrapped them with Supplier. How can I reference the list inside the Supplier get() call.

Comment: @mitali It's hard to understand what exactly you need without seeing your actual code. In general, each time you call the `Supplier`'s `get()`, you have to store a reference to the created `List` somewhere. Otherwise it's useless.