# LocalDate in java stores UTC date or local date?

Tags: java, date, utc, localdate

reading documentation about LocalDate in Java, the documentation says LocalDate.now() "Obtains the current date from the system clock in the default time-zone.". So if I am in Madrid-Spain and lets imagine right now is 28-09-2022 01:12(GMT+02:00)

1. The date stored in LocalDate is 28-09-2022, not 27-09-2022 that would be UTC date. Right?
2. When you print a LocalDate, it is not considered the timezone of the system to print it because LocalDate does not have any timezone information, just print the value stored, right?.
3. So, there are differences with Date objects because Date objects store UTC date and times, right?
4. The documentation says "This class does not store or represent a date or time-zone", so in order to do the next, how can it be done the second sentence if localDate has not timezone information?

   ```
       LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

       ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("EST5EDT"));

       System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
   ```

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. Not exactly, an old-fashioned `Date` object just stores a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 UTC. It doesn't know anything about timezones. That the reference point is UTC does not mean it only stores UTC date and times. 4. What do you mean? That code takes a `LocalDate` and combines it with timezone information to create a `ZonedDateTime`, which *does* contain timezone information.

Comment: To reduce confusion I recommend you don’t use the no-arg `LocalDate.now` method but rather `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))` or `LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))` (in your example these two will give different results).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Jesper has [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885949/localdate-in-java-stores-utc-date-or-local-date/73886431#comment130462661_73885949) all your questions. However, it seems he perceived your Q#2 in a way different from what you may be thinking. Your Q#2 is:

> When you print a LocalDate, it is not considered the timezone of the
> system to print it because LocalDate does not have any timezone
> information, just print the value stored, right?.

The fact is, when you print a `LocalDate`, it always considers the timezone of the system e.g. if you print `LocalDate.now()` in Madrid, India and New York at the same time, you may get different results (depending on what time you do it). Probably, this is what Ole V.V. has tried to tell you in his comment.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09-28
2022-09-29
2022-09-28
```

To understand this difference, I suggest you print `LocalDateTime` instead of just `LocalDate` e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09-28T21:03:56.438167
2022-09-29T00:33:56.443577
2022-09-28T15:03:56.444049
```

Comment: About question 2, what I meant is that when you create a LocalDate, it is always considered the timezone of the system or the zoneId you pass as a parameter to create the date, but once you already have the date created, if you print it is not considered the timezone, it was at the time of creating it, not when printing it. That was my question

Comment: @fernando1979 If I have understood your comment correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040099/10819573) can be helpful to you.

Comment: I think the important distinction here is between a `LocalDate` *object* and the static no-arg `now` method of the `LocalDate` *class*. The object *never* considers the system time zone. The no-arg method *always* does.

Comment: @fernando1979 If I understand you correctly, you are correct: When you create the `LocalDate` using one of the `now` methods, time zone is considered (and system time zone of none is given in the call). After that the `LocalDate` object is never altered again, so when you print it, all that is considered is the state it got in creation.

Comment: "print a LocalDate" is confusing wording in your prose. I suggest you more distinctly separate the issues of (a) capturing the current date (zone involved), (b) representing simply the year-month-day with a `LocalDate` object (no zone involved, and (c) `LocalDate.toString` generating text, but no text inside `LocalDate` object (no zone).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Question # 4 was answered well. I think it is obvious to Jasper and others but not so obvious to me and I think OP.

`LocalDateTime.now()` will use either system clock or provided timezone to determine what "now" is, but then removes the time zone reference. It is impossible to determine what original time zone was used to create the `LocalDateTime` object.

That had me wondering how does `LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))` properly convert the `LocalDateTime` to `Europe/Madrid` timezone if there is no time zone reference point to convert from? For example, if `LocalDateTime` is 2022-09-28T21:03:56, how can it then convert that to Europe/Madrid when it does not understand what time zone the date/time it holds originated from?

The solution is obvious now. It doesn't convert and it does not try to figure out what timezone it originated from. It just appends the timezone specified to the date/time it has.

So if a `LocalDateTime` object has a value of 2022-09-28T21:03:56, then `LocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))` instantiates a `ZonedDateTime` object with a value of 2022-09-28T21:03:56+01:00. Notice there is no change other than adding the +01:00 offset in use by the people of that time zone at that moment.

If that particular time-of-day does not exist in that time zone at that moment, such as during a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover, the time-of-day in the new `ZonedDateTime` is adjusted logically.

After I understood those two points it was all really clear how it worked.

Hope this helps someone else that this was not that obvious for.

Comment: I reworded your last half to be more precise, more explicit. And I added a bit about how the new `ZonedDateTime` will have its time-of-day adjusted if need be.

Comment: You make valuable points here in this Answer. But unfortunately, it is off-topic for this Question. This Question does not involve the `LocalDateTime` class nor the concept behind that class. This have been better placed as an Answer to a new and separate Question you authored. (Answering your own Question is not only allowed, it is encouraged on Stack Overflow.)