# Creating Supplier stream of Stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future

I am creating a Supplier Stream of String and working on the same.

```java
public void test(Stream<String> s) {
    Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> s;

    System.out.println(streamSupplier.get().count());

    streamSupplier.get().parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 2))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .forEach(input -> {
            System.out.println("input " + input);
        });
```

I am getting an error "stream has already been operated upon or closed" when I try to work with the stream. How can I resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: A stream instance can only be used once. This supplier returns the same stream instance each time `get` is called. Typically, suppliers should return a new instance on each invocation.

Comment: What do you mean by "stream of stream"? And at which line in your code do you get that error message? Please edit your question and add the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040099/10819573) to learn more about how to use a `Supplier` of `Stream`.

Comment: Since a stream instance can only be used once, we can modified the code as below:  `List<String> slist = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(slist.size());

        Stream<String> s1 = slist.stream();
        Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> s1;

        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        streamSupplier.get().parallel()`
...

Comment: @NeoJou this is giving me an error as well.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am using the supplier stream in the example above, the issue I am facing is that I am working with an already created stream. Thanks

Comment: @Tanu Since Stream<String> s is the parameter of the test, is it possible that the Steam<String> s is already consumed before entering to run in this test function? I did a simple test problem at https://github.com/neojou/java_on_macOS/blob/main/SupplierExample/src/Main.java and it runs well here. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve with this one, but a stream can only be used once. Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

I think that you want to have a re-usable stream, so in this case I would suggest you pass in the original collection instead of the `Stream` of this collection dataset.

Comment: I want to find an alternative, that is something I cannot control. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. It is a different problem the user is facing. Thanks