Update Spock mock from different threads
I am testing code that runs in its own thread in a while loop. The code under test does some stuff based on the current time, then updates an AtomicReference<Integer>
The application logic is an algorithm that runs for days. I need to simulate the behavior by controlling the time readings, and checking the computed results.
I can't figure out how to mock the time. When clock time gets updated from Spock test, the ClassUnderTest.run() thread does not see the new value.
I provided simplified code examples below.
Code under test
class ClassUnderTest {
    private ExecutorService executorService = ...
    private MyClock clock;
    private AtomicReference<Integer> result = ...

    public ClassUnderTest(MyClock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;

        // start the thread
        this.executorService.submit(this::run);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (hasThreeHoursPassed(clock.getTime()) { // <-- PROBLEM, can't mock getTime() from Spock thread
                // ... core application logic that requires testing ...
                result.set(...);
            }
        }
   }
}

Spock test
def 'test thread' () {
    given:
    MyClock clockMock = Mock(MyClock)
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = ClassUnderTest(clockMock)
    long mockedTime = 1L;
    clockMock.getTime() >> mockedTime

    expect:
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mockedTime += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3 // 3 hours

        clockMock.getTime() >> mockedTime // <-- PROBLEM, this does not work. The thread does not see this value

        classUnderTest.getResult() == ... expected value ...
    }


}

It is important to note that the logic being tested is itself the behavior of the code being executed over time. I tried to keep the code sample simple for readability. The real application logic is an algorithm that maintains a data structure that changes over time (it is a time based decaying algorithm to rank popular content based on views).

Not sure if I understand correctly,you want the clock.getTime() to be controlled by you or be invoked with defined value in test.If thats the case,you could use Supplier which will be initialised for every testcase Supplier<MyClock> s= ()->MyClock(1L);

RE "you want the clock.getTime() to be controlled by you or be invoked with defined value in test" -- I want both ... but the control I need is to update the value of clock from Spock test thread, while the ClassUnderTest.run() thread can read the values. I'm guessing Spock mock does not support multi threading, which is why I can't seem to update the value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41647209/10362945
Close to what you want

If at all possible I'd advise you to refactor your ClassUnderTest so that you can just invoke the logic directly.
class ClassUnderTest {
    private ExecutorService executorService = ...
    private MyClock clock;
    private AtomicReference<Integer> result = ...

    public ClassUnderTest(MyClock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;

        // start the thread
        this.executorService.submit(this::run);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (hasThreeHoursPassed(clock.getTime()) { // <-- PROBLEM, can't mock getTime() from Spock thread
                performApplicationLogic()
            }
        }
   }

   @VisibleForTesting
   void performApplicationLogic() {
       // ... core application logic that requires testing ...
       result.set(...);
   }
}

Then you can just call it a 100 times if you need. I would also decouple the executor submit from the constructor, or add another constructor that doesn't start the thread as it will not be necessary for the testing.
def 'test decoupled' () {
    given:
    MyClock clockMock = Mock(MyClock)
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = ClassUnderTest(clockMock, false) // new constructor with false indicating not starting the test.
    long mockedTime = 1L;
    clockMock.getTime() >> mockedTime

    when:
    def results = []
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        classUnderTest.performApplicationLogic()
        results << classUnderTest.getResult()
    }

    then:
    // assert that the results match the expected values
}

If you still need to modify the time returned by the mock then use an AtomicLong and a computed return value.
    def mockedTime = new AtomicLong(1L);
    clockMock.getTime() >> { mockedTime.get() }

    when:
    def results = []
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mockedTime.addAndGet(1000 * 60 * 60 * 3)  // 3 hours
        classUnderTest.performApplicationLogic()
        results << classUnderTest.getResult()
    }

As an aside, use a ScheduledExecutorService instead of creating a busy loop with while(true).

Valid points. What you're suggesting is more of a unit testing strategy. The goal here is to test the logic of the application over time. We need to catch regressions that happen after a few hours or days of the production algorithms execution. We could probably consider this more of an integration test.

Either you've left out important information, or I fail to see how the strategy of testing you proposed is any different, other than being more cumbersome. It will also not test anything over a long period of time.

Leonard, I think you are right, I likely left out some information that makes the difference in your argument. The actual logic being tested is itself the behavior of the algorithm over time. This process is a "popularity ranking" algorithm for distributing content across CDN tiers, and it decays content popularity over time

And you can't just use the mocked time in performApplicationLogic() to calculate the decay? And how would your initial attempt have made any difference?

When I update the mocked time from the Spock test thread, the time that is being read from the ClassUnderTest.run() Task thread, which executes performApplicationLogic() never gets updated

I'm thinking to change the structure of ClassUnderTest to have a constructor that does not start a worker thread. Then, from Spock test, I will launch the thread. That should allow me to interrupt the thread and update the clock as needed. I'll report back if that works

Can you share some of your new test code of what you are planning to do? It still sounds more complicated. How is interrupting the thread better than just calling the performApplicationLogic() method from the test? Think of it as using a ScheduledExecutorService with scheduleAtFixedRate only that you call the method directly instead of using the service in the test scenario. WRT no updates, did you try to use the AtomicLong and computed response like I showed at the end of my answer?

I didn't see that last part of your answer before, I think that might work. I suspect that the ClassUnderTest.run() thread is holding on to a cached value for clock time, and I presume using an atomic/volatile dynamic value should take care of that. I also agree that it is simpler. Let me give this a shot

This worked, thanks. I bet that the clock variable was being cached by the worker thread and did not see the updates made in my unit test, since it wasn't volatile. I'm glad I ran into this issue because I never really understood these concurrency mechanisms before!

No, it was not cached, you just can't override what an unrestricted stub will return. As each call of clockMock.getTime() >> mockedTime will just add another interaction to the list with the current value of mockedTime. However, as the first interaction does not have limits it will always match first and the newer interactions will never be executed. Using an mutable AtomicLong together with computed return values side steps that behavior.

Leonard, I don't understand what you mean by first interaction does not have limits it will always match first and the newer interactions will never be executed. Are you suggesting doing obj.method() >> value1 and then later updating it to obj.method() >> value2 will cause it to always return value1? What is meant by "limits" ?

Yes, it is a misconception that you are updating the mock. See the docs about limits/cardinality, interaction order, stubbing, and combining mocking and stubbing.
